# Using playa to get entries

Tags: playa, relationships, entry

one called "crops" one is named "products".

Crops linked to products, through a playa field for the products channel.

At the moment my tag produces a list of crops but many are repeated.

When populating a crops menu, I want to query those crops who are linked to a product. This way, crops for which we dont have products assigned aren't listed.  I want a unique entry for each crop that has 1 or more products associated to it.

Any ideas?

*Update*

Here is the code I left out last time...

```
{if segment_2=="crops"}
<div class="box plants">
    <h2>Φυτά</h2>
<select>
    <option {if segment_2==""}selected="selected"{/if} value="/index.php/products/">όλa</option>
        {exp:channel:entries channel="products" orderby="title" sort="asc" dynamic="no"}
            {exp:playa:children channel="crops"}
                {if count>0}
                    <option {if segment_3==url_title}selected="selected" {/if} value="/index.php/products/crops/{url_title}">{title}</option>
                {/if}
            {/exp:playa:children}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
</select>
</div>
{/if}
```

The playa relationship is a field in products channel that links to entries (fieldname={crops})in the crops channel. Not sure whether this is revers relationship or not.

Comment: A little more info would be helpful. What is your current template code, what are the custom fields named? Which one is the playa relationship? Will this be a reverse relationship or a regular one?

Comment: Hey CreateSean, I've updated my query as per your request! let me know if I can provide more details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly this problems, and I used [Nested Entries](https://github.com/iainurquhart/Nested-Entries) instead. Maybe this can help you too.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="country"}
    {title}
    {exp:nested:prep_vars var_prefix="nested_"}
        {exp:nested:entries channel="office" dynamic="off" search:cf_office_country="{title}"}
            Office: {nested_title}
        {/exp:nested:entries}
    {/exp:nested:prep_vars}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: This is great! Has helped loads and has allowed me to really cool stuff with nested playa fields. Thank you ianisted!